# How can I parse the output of trace-cmd report using awk?

Tags: parsing, awk, ftrace

The only thing I need to see in the output is which functions were called.

Input:

```
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416466: funcgraph_entry:                   |  ib_enum_all_devs() {
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416472: funcgraph_entry:      + 29.337 us  |    ib_get_device_fw_str();
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416504: funcgraph_exit:       + 38.787 us  |  }
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416543: funcgraph_entry:        1.191 us   |  ib_enum_all_devs();
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416621: funcgraph_entry:        1.371 us   |  ib_device_get_by_index();
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416624: funcgraph_entry:                   |  ib_get_client_nl_info() {
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416628: funcgraph_entry:        0.890 us   |    ib_uverbs_get_nl_info();
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416630: funcgraph_exit:         6.174 us   |  }
```

The output should look like this:

```
ib_enum_all_devs() {
 ib_get_device_fw_str();
}
ib_enum_all_devs();
ib_device_get_by_index();
ib_get_client_nl_info() {
 ib_uverbs_get_nl_info();
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
cat myfile.dat | awk '{print $7}'
```

However, this gives me garbage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you use the pipe character as a field separator?

```
cat myfile.dat | awk -F "|" '{print $2}'
```

... and as usual I've done [a useless use of `cat`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11710552/useless-use-of-cat):

```
awk -F "|" '{print $2}' file.txt
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use this `awk`:

```bash
awk -F '  \\|  ' '{print $NF}' file

ib_enum_all_devs() {
  ib_get_device_fw_str();
}
ib_enum_all_devs();
ib_device_get_by_index();
ib_get_client_nl_info() {
  ib_uverbs_get_nl_info();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I would harness GNU `AWK` for this task following let `file.txt`

```
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416466: funcgraph_entry:                   |  ib_enum_all_devs() {
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416472: funcgraph_entry:      + 29.337 us  |    ib_get_device_fw_str();
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416504: funcgraph_exit:       + 38.787 us  |  }
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416543: funcgraph_entry:        1.191 us   |  ib_enum_all_devs();
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416621: funcgraph_entry:        1.371 us   |  ib_device_get_by_index();
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416624: funcgraph_entry:                   |  ib_get_client_nl_info() {
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416628: funcgraph_entry:        0.890 us   |    ib_uverbs_get_nl_info();
ibv_rc_pingpong-759367 [005] 8391981.416630: funcgraph_exit:         6.174 us   |  }
```

then

```
awk '{print substr($0, 84)}' file.txt
```

gives output

```
ib_enum_all_devs() {
  ib_get_device_fw_str();
}
ib_enum_all_devs();
ib_device_get_by_index();
ib_get_client_nl_info() {
  ib_uverbs_get_nl_info();
}
```

Explanation: you have file with fixed-width column, I simply use [`substr`](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/String-Functions.html) function to get part of whole line (`$0`) starting at 84th character.

*(tested in GNU Awk 5.0.1)*